# Can I transfer game data from one Xbox One to another?

Tags: xbox-one

If I have my game data on one console with my account, is there a way to continue playing it on a different Xbox One and a different game disc?

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you are asking if you can carry your save game from one Xbox One to another. Yes you can, but only is you use Xbox Live and have a Gold subscription to backup your save games to the cloud. Then you'll access the same profile on the 2nd Xbox, and you can download the save game.

Xbox Live Gold is a payed service.

You can't copy it to an USB flash drive.

Comment: um, well.  you can actually.  the USB has to be Xbox formatted (which it does when you plug it in and go through those steps).  You can then take that external hard drive to another Xbox and play from your saved game

Comment: I don't have an XBoxOne, I was going by XBox's website. USB HDDs can be used to store games and media, and USB pen drives smaller than 256MB, can be used to store Media. I know you could do it on the 360, but I can't find online proof you can do it on XBox One.

Comment: My source: http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-one/accessories/usb-port-use

Comment: I've used a thumb drive on my 360 before.  Granted, I don't remember the size of it, but I have used one.  Honestly, I don't have digital proof that I've done it.  That's why it's not an answer on here.  But it is feasible to use a thumb drive.  I just don't know what the minimum requirements are for it.

Comment: The question is about XBox One, not XBox 360. Like I said, I know it's possible on the XBox 360, I've got 2 360s myself. I don't have an XBox One though, and the online website leads me to believe it's not possible anymore. I bet it's because the usb pen savegames, was a constant source of cheats and mods on the XB360, so MS closed that door.

Comment: I've done it on both.  I just don't remember what size my thumb drive was.  I now have an external 2 TB because of the many games I've been playing

Comment: I'm sorry, I guess I wasn't very clear on that. Sorry about tha